# GridView.Rows[i].DataItem равен null

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource 
    ID="odsSeniority" 
    runat="server" 
    TypeName="Pipeline.DAL.SosrBat" 
    SelectMethod="EmployeeCollectionWithFilter">
    <SelectParameters>
        <!-- Параметры -->
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="grvSeniority" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="odsSeniority"
    DataKeyNames="tbn" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<!-- Поля связаны -->
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ТН" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TBN")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Но в итоге `grvSeniority.Rows[i].DataItem` равен `null`. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Цитата из [статьи](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.aspx) MSDN.

> Свойство DataItem доступно только во время и после события RowDataBound элемента управления GridView.

И еще попробуйте вместо `<%# Bind("TBN")%>` использовать `<%#Eval("TBN")%>`.

Если не будет получаться, можно взять целиком пример из MSDN и подогнать под себя.

Comment: спасибо за старания, но ситуация не изменилась...:(